# Which colour is "rosinfarben"?

Tags: meaning, adjective, history

I participated recently in a choir where we worked on Crato Bütner’s motet *[Wir dancken dir, Herr Jesu Christ](http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Wir_danken_dir,_Herr_Jesu_Christ_%28Crato_B%C3%BCtner%29)*. This work is not performed frequently and, apparently, the few copies of the score that are around derive from a manuscript preserved in Uppsala University Library. It is a baroque composition, so expectably spelling etc. differs from the contemporary. (Needless to add, my command of German is limited.)

I quote one stanza of the text:

> Und wie der Schächer zur rechten Hand
>   auf seine Buße Gnade für dir fandt,
>   also bitt ich gib du mir _
>   über meine Sünde, o Christe _,
>   durch dein **rosinfarbes** Blut
>   daß du vergoßen aus sanftem Mut.

Emphasis mine. (Both the rhythm and the rhyming pattern indicate two missing words; that is however immaterial here.)

We were a bit puzzled by the collocation *rosinfarbes Blut.* According to Duden, the contemporary meaning is self-explanatory: [*rosinfarben*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rosinfarben) means *von der Farbe einer Rosine.* The word would appear to be infrequent.

As this seemed the wrong colour for blood, I had an online glimpse into *Historisches Lexikon deutscher Farbbezeichnungen*, which seems to document *rosinfarbes* for many different colours, from rose to crimson to raisin-coloured.

I would like, if possible, to get more background for the meaning usage of this word. In particular, my questions are:

- whether it is at all used nowadays;
- how the meaning has shifted, and whether it could have stood for different colours depending on the collocation;
- what the etymology is for this word.

Comment: As an afterthought, perhaps Bütner opted for the -i- spelling variant also to achieve better resonance: the short phrase _rosinfarbes Blut_ happily accomodates all the vowels (umlaut excluded): -o-i-a-e-u-. The line introduces a new musical theme, and is repeated three times (I think), so the effect is magnificent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### "Rosinrot" was a variant of "[rosenrot](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR07513#XGR07513)"

In addition to the rarely used term depciting the color of raisins "[rosinrot](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR07659#XGR07659)" used to be a variant of "rosenrot" for red as a rose. This color was used for intense red colors:

> Dürft' ich sie umfahn und küssen auf den rosenrothen Mund. <sup>Uhland</sup>

Until today we may hear "rosige Wangen", "rosige Lippen" even though it appears to be less frequent.

For colors, building a composite adjective with the actual main color (e.g. *veilchenblau*, *karottengelb*) or the suffix *-farbig* is also possible (*veilchenfarbig*, *karottenfarbig*).

Obviouly when using "**rosinfarbig**" as another possible adjective Crato Bütner was influenced by Martin Luther who preferably used "rosinrot" in his German translation of The Holy Bible:

[image]

<sup>[Martin Luther: Biblia, Das ist, die gantze heilige Schrifft Deudsch](https://books.google.de/books?id=6Ps7AGb7b4QC&lpg=PT93&ots=ctKhHsuptS&dq=luther%20rosinrot&pg=PT93#v=onepage&q=luther%20rosinrot&f=false) (1535)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. So it would seem that 'rosinfarbes' is primarily deep red, and the "raisin" trail is merely incidental.

Comment: Yeah entirely incidental, as the etymology of "Rosine" (like English *raisin*) is from French *raisin* (Latin *racemus* = berry) whereas "Rose" (*rose*) is from Latin *rosa*. "Rot" and *red* is a very old word in all Indo-European language from Indian *rudhiráḥ*.

Comment: @Takkat: The Sanskrit word is *not* the source: it’s simply another reflex of the Proto-Indo-European root *h1reudh-, though where English *red* and German *rot* are from the *o*-grade adjective *h1roudhós, the Sanskrit word is from the zero-grade form *h1rudhrós (along with Latin *ruber* and Greek *eruthrós*).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you - we can go further back in time as long as there are sources ;) *"The only color for which a definite common PIE root word has been found."* says http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=red&searchmode=none

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the link you gave states

> ...
>   durch dein **rosen**farbes Blut
>   ...

"rosenfarbes Blut" translates to "rose-coloured blood" which stands simply for: 
**red** blood.

Comment: True. The CPDL edition gives 'rosenfarbes'. My edition gives 'rosinfarbes' though. (The script we used did not come from CPDL.) Funny thing is, 'rosinfarbes' exists and was historically used for all those shades of red, in particular collocated with blood, as I try to explain in the post. So I just wondered. (Admittedly, our edition contained a few misprints.)

Comment: You're right, apparently it's just a spelling variant. Thanks. (I'm accepting Takkat's answer as it's spoonfeeding more of the story.)